Diffusions vs elliptic operators with dkp coefficients
I am wondering if there is any literature on the relationship between diffusions and elliptic equations. In particular I am interested in literature concerning operators with Dahlberg–Kenig–Pipher coefficients in domains.
I have looked around but usually people working in stochastic analysis tend to assume that the coefficients are lipschitz and don't blow up at the boundary. More than anything I am looking for some literature on the connection between stochastic processes and elliptic operators with such rough coefficients. Any help is appreciated.

I think Bass’s book Diffusions and Elliptic Operators covers possible explosion, and only locally Lipschitz or Sobolev coefficients. But I cannot remember very well as it has been awhile since I looked at this reference. Apologies if I misremembered.
